# Concordance des temps

Tags: conjugaison, subjonctif, concordance-des-temps

Je butte sur une formulation.  J'ai l'impression que la grammaire et l'oreille luttent dans cette phrase :)

> Enfin, la circulation reprendrait normalement, sans qu'on puisse soupçonner qu'un drame **soit** survenu à cet endroit.

ou

> Enfin, la circulation reprendrait normalement, sans qu'on puisse soupçonner qu'un drame **est** survenu à cet endroit.

ou les deux sont fausses ?

Auquel cas, comment pourrait-on dire ?

Comment: l'imparfait de reprendre, c'est reprenait, à la troisième personne. reprendrait, c'est le conditionnel.

Comment: @Lambie Pourquoi ce commentaire ?

Comment: Peut être une description alors, mais plus de contexte aiderait à comprendre mieux.

Comment: @Lambie Mieux vaut alors demander clairement une explication si tu ne comprends pas bien une phrase plutôt que de lancer une affirmation hors sujet.

Answer (score 1):

Le verbe de la principale est au conditionnel (→ la circulation **reprendrait** normalement), on est dans l'irréel, je n'emploierais donc pas l'indicatif pour exprimer un drame qui n'a jamais eu lieu.

> Enfin, la circulation reprendrait normalement, sans qu'on puisse soupçonner qu'un drame soit survenu à cet endroit.

Si on quitte l’élaboration d'un scénario pour décrire un fait avéré, il me semble que théoriquement les deux, indicatif comme subjonctif, soient possibles après *soupçonner*.

> Enfin, la circulation reprend normalement, sans qu'on puisse soupçonner qu'un drame soit survenu à cet endroit. (1)

> Enfin, la circulation reprend normalement, sans qu'on puisse soupçonner qu'un drame est survenu à cet endroit. (2)

(2) rend le drame plus proche que (1), mais personnellement je n'aime pas l'emploi de l'indicatif ici.

Comment: On ne peut pas exclure le cas où un drame à bien eu lieu, mais où c'est la reprise de la circulation qui est hypothétique. Dans ce cas *reprendrait* + *est survenu* est valide.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai beau tourner et retourner la phrase dans ma tête je n'arrive pas à ton interprétation, avec la phrase telle qu'elle est formulée  dans la question.

Comment: Si tu retires *enfin* de la phrase, est-ce que ça change ton avis ?

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne le vois toujours pas ainsi, pour moi *enfin* n'interfère pas dans le rapport de subordination entre les deux actions, c'est *sans que*. Enfin, la circulation reprendrait, on ne pourrait pas soupçonner pas qu'un drame est survenu à cet endroit.

Comment: Pour moi, si Zofren se pose la question, c'est que le drame est un fait réel. Le deuxième scénario maladroitement exprimé par LPH s'approche de cette éventualité.

Answer (score -1):

Tout dépend du contexte. On se place dans un contexte de base où le conditionnel est justifié, et donc la circulation reprend normalement dans un contexte hypotétique, par example, dès que les véhicules auraient été déplacés sur le bas-côté. Dans ce contexte de base, où le déplacement est hypothétique, est aussi  considéré en plus un accident hypothétique, et la première phrase convient (« soit » pour le second verbe).

- Les images satellite permettent de déterminer les responsabilités dans tout accident de la route ; les nécessités d'un constat de police ne sont plus nécessaires. Il s'ensuit que si un accident arrivait, après que les victimes auraient été secourues, s'il y en avait, il ne serait plus utile de maintenir les véhicules sur la chaussée et d'attendre qu'un constat soit fait et qu'ils soient enlevés. Il y aurait donc la possibilité d'envoyer un camion conçu spécialement pour pousser rapidement les véhicules accidentés sur le côté. Après quoi, il n'y aurait plus qu'à déployer une barrière en roseau entre les véhicules et la voie.
  Enfin, la circulation **reprendrait** normalement, sans qu'on puisse soupçonner qu'un drame **soit** survenu à cet endroit.

Le type de contexte pris en compte ci-dessus est peut-être le plus habituel ; il y en a cependant au moins un autre. Des personnes  discutent une nouvelle façon plus rapide de rétablir la circulation après un accident. Le responsable chargé de l'information sur ce nouveau projet peut choisir l'approche particulière suivante lorsqu'il devient question de mettre divers intéressés au courant et qu'il veut appuyer son explication par un exemple ;  il peut commencer par supposer qu'un accident est arrivé à un point donné d'une route connue.

- Supposons qu'un accident entre deux voitures est arrivé sur la RN 104 à X. Si on procède selon la nouvelle méthode voilà ce qui se passerait. Après qu'on aurait porté  secours aux victimes le camion de déblayage pousserait les deux véhicules accidentés sur le côté en un dixième du temps nécessaire pour les enlever. Déployer la barrière en roseau entre les véhicules et la voie ne serait qu'un jeu d'enfant.
  Enfin, la circulation **reprendrait** normalement, sans qu'on puisse soupçonner qu'un drame **est** survenu à cet endroit.

Comment: Le contexte : le narrateur est en train de décrire un carambolage ayant eu lieu et imagine ce qu'il va se passer par la suite, finissant par cette phrase.

Comment: @Zofren Dans ce cas le conditionnel pour « reprendre » est bizarre, à moins qu'en plus de la description se trouve dans le texte une hypothèse, qui, si réalisée, serait une garantie pour que la circulation reprenne normalement. Autrement, je ne comprends pas.